# Microsoft Exchange Web Services Connectivity Tests, Error: failed to create temporary folder for performing tests

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to "Exchange Web Services synchronization, notification, availability, and Automatic Replies" test from testconnectivity.microsoft.com.

But it fails with following error: 
Creating a temporary folder to perform synchronization tests.
Failed to create temporary folder for performing tests.

Full detailed error:

```
Additional Details

Exception details:
Message: The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Type: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException
Stack trace:
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalBindToFolders(IEnumerable`1 folderIds, PropertySet propertySet, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToFolder[TFolder](FolderId folderId, PropertySet propertySet)
at Microsoft.Exchange.Tools.ExRca.Tests.GetOrCreateSyncFolderTest.PerformTestReally()
Exception details:
Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Type: System.Net.WebException
Stack trace:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
Exception details:
Message: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
Type: System.IO.IOException
Stack trace:
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
Elapsed Time: 180 ms.
```

This is how our Exchange environment configured.

We have 4 Exchange server, 3 with CAS role. The connection is load balanced using Kemp load balancer and we are using TMG to present our OWA and configure Autodiscover for the Internet.

Please help with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our TMG website IIS website (newly created) virtual directories were the problem. To test this we create a direct firewall rule to send traffic to Kemp Loadbalancer IP of TMG IIS Website on our exchange server and we had the same issue. Then we directed the traffic to our Default IIS Website on our exchange server the test analyzer showed no errors.

So the problem was the TMG IIS Website Virtual directory for autodiscover and EWS services that is residing on our exchange server.

We have now created a rule to accept exchange online traffic on a separate external IP and send it our Exchange IIS Default Website.

**Update:**

There was further change where we had to take load-balancer completely out of the setup because it was modifying our email header and due to that all emails sent between Exchange Online and Exchange on-prem were marked as anonymous instead of internal. This cause an issue where our meeting rooms were not accepting the booking invitation.

If you need more info, leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that your CAS servers are being front ended by the Kemp Load Balancer. Given that you are seeing issues with the MS Exchange behavior, our recommendation would be to visit our [support center](http://support.kemptechnologies.com). There you can review related documentation or submit a ticket to our support team. If the LoadMaster is contributing to the behavior our engineers would be able to assist.